# Prevent login to user and custom guards at the same time

Tags: laravel

I am using a custom guard for a different type of user using a custom guard labelled `business_user`.

I have noticed I am able to login to as both normal users (web) and my `business_users`.
I've read in the [Pusher documentation](https://pusher.com/tutorials/multiple-authentication-guards-laravel) that I used to create my custom guards in the first place to add additional middleware into my "LoginController".

But I don't actually even have a LoginController, I've created my own controllers for each user type. AuthController (for web) and BusinessController (for business_user).

I have created a third controller labelled LoginController with the following code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
        $this->middleware('guest:business_user')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

I also updated my `RedirectIfAuthenticated` as follows:

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if ($guard == "business_user" && Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/dashboard');
        }
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

I also have a `RedirectIfAuthenticated` middleware inside my Middleware folder.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if ($guard == "business_user" && Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/dashboard');
        }
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

When I land on my user login page, it still allows me to attempt logging in. Can someone tell me how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

In LoginController, you can override `authenticated` method.

```php
/**
  * The user has been authenticated.
  *
  * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
  * @param  mixed  $user
  * @return mixed
*/
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
   auth()->login($user); // this method will login with default guard
   return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath()); 
}
```

Comment: How does this answer my question?

Comment: I think you have to attempt user when the business user has been authenticated

Answer (score 0):

I think because the order of middleware

```php
<?php

public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout'); // this procress first and redirect to login page
        $this->middleware('guest:business_user')->except('logout');
    }
```

So, I think you can check directly in `__construct()` of `LoginController` or in login view (`blade` file)

```
@if (Auth::check('business_user'))
    You are already logged in (or perform a redirect somewhere)
@else
    //display login form
@endif
```